# I might have just deleted half of my project through git. I Need to know ifany of it is recoverable

Tags: git

About an hour ago I commited to my repository with sensitive info. So I "git rebase -i HEAD~1" and deleted the commit. I thought this would delete the commit on github so I could re-commit without the sensitive info. Unfortunately, it deleted the commit and then forced the old state on to my local files. All the files that I had in the old commit, I am able to CTRL-Z and get their states as they just were, but all the files I've added since then are gone. Is there any way to get them back. They were just on my machine but I don't see them in the trash. So much time will be lost if I cant retrieve them.

Comment: In the "open editors" tab in vs code I was able to find a few of them, but there are still many missing.